# How to load Handlebars runtime with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm new to RequireJS and trying to load handlebars precompiled templates with RequireJS.  It load the handlebars template and runtime but Handlebars runtime was undefined.

**Folders structure**

```
www
 |__index.html
 |__js
    |__main.js
    |__lib
    |    |__jquery-1.10.1.min.js
    |    |__handlebars.runtime-v1.1.2.js
    |    |__require.js
    |__modules
    |    |__content.js
    |__templates
         |__content-tmpl.js     //handlebars precompiled template
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'lib/jquery-1.10.1.min',
        'handlebars.runtime':'lib/handlebars.runtime-v1.1.2'
    }
});
requirejs(['modules/content','jquery'],function (content,$) {

    $(function(){
        content.initModule();
    });
});
```

**content.js**

```
define(['jquery','../templates/content-tmpl'],function($,template){
    return{
        initModule:function(){
            $('body').append(template());
        }
    }
});
```

**content-tmpl.js (Compiled Handlebars template)**

```
define(['handlebars.runtime'], function (Handlebars) {

//Error raise here. Handlebars is undefined.

    Handlebars = Handlebars["default"];
    var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
    return templates['content'] = template(function (Handlebars, depth0, helpers, partials, data) {
        this.compilerInfo = [4, '>= 1.0.0'];
        helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers);
        data = data || {};
        return "<div>\r\n    Hello Handlebars and RequireJS\r\n</div>";
    });
});
```

**Console Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
```

Comment: Has anyone been able to find a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem and not sure what needs to happen. Sounds like a lot of people are running into this.

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `handlebars.runtime.js` is not an AMD module, so you need to configure it using shim config. In your require.js config add

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    "handlebars.runtime": {
      exports: "Handlebars"
    }
  }
});
```

This way, when you call `require("handlebars.runtime")`, require.js will know to grab window.Handlebars variable and pass it to you after the script has loaded.

Comment: Handlebars 1.3 has an AMD version, so you should be able to require it directly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RequireJS, you should be including the AMD version of the runtime in which case no exporting is required.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'handlebars.runtime': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.runtime.amd.min'
    }
});
```

Then when you want to access the Handlebars object (e.g. to register a helper).

```
require(['handlebars.runtime'], function(HandlebarsRuntime) {
    var Handlebars = HandlebarsRuntime.default;
});
```

You can see an example of an up-to-date application using compiled Handlebars templates and RequireJS at https://github.com/ryan-blunden/handlebars-requrejs